# DataGridView with relation(Show name, not id)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

**Description:**

I have a problem regarding `DataGridView`. I need to show a `Client_Name` instead of `Id_client`
This is the `Product` table and it has a relationship with the `Client`table.

**IMAGE :** 
[image]

I'm using Access DB and DataSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid having to do multiple queries to get the client name for each product you should include on your query an inner join to Clients table and return the client name along with the product data.

```
SELECT      pro.*, cli.[Name] as ClientName 
FROM        Products pro
INNER JOIN  Clients cli ON cli.Id = pro.ClientId
```

We could help more if you specify your data access strategy.

Comment: I using Access DB and DataSet, but how i create a binding with id and name?

Comment: Not sure if I follow but if you do the query as I indicating you will already have the client name on your data set so you just need to bind it as you're doing for any other field